# can't get attribute's name and value while parsing xml

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I have got a non empty `pugi::xml_node my_node;`.

If I print it with `my_node.print(std::cout);` I can clearly see that the contents of this node are okay.
Let's say it's:

```
<my_class id="0" name="my class" type="my type">
   <child_1> 45.0 </child_1>
   <child_2> 0.01 </child_2>
   <child_3> 100.0 </child_3>
   <child_4> some_string </child_4>
</my_class>
```

But when I try to iterate it's attributes, I get weird output (which looks like some kind of addresses?).

```
for (auto attr : my_node.attributes()){
    std::cout << attr.name() << " : " << attr.value() << std::endl;
}
```

And here's the output:

```
0x55727e049cd4 : 0x55727e049ce4
0x55727e049d1c : 0x55727e049d34
0x55727e049d8c : 0x55727e049da4
```

I took this example from the documentation by the way and I've got no idea why this is happening.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name()` and `value()` methods return `const char_t*`.

`char_t` is Pugi-specific typedef, controlled by `PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE` macro.

What I think happened, you have defined `PUGIXML_WCHAR_MODE`, `char_t` becomes `wchar_t`, however `std::cout` is not Unicode. If that’s the case, try using Unicode output instead, like this:

```
std::wcout << attr.name() << L" : " << attr.value() << std::endl;
```